# IPFS - pubsub connect to peers from browser

Tags: p2p, ipfs

I am running an ipfs node in the browser using the following config:

```
const node = new IPFS({ 
  repo: 'ipfs-' + Math.random(),
  EXPERIMENTAL: {
    pubsub: true,
  },
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

I have subscribed to a topic and can find peers + message them across browser tabs but not on the internet!

I am using ipfs-js and packaging it via webpack.

How do I discover and message peers across the network?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
      API: '',
      Gateway: '',
```

to your `Addresses` like so:

```
const node = new IPFS({ 
  repo: 'ipfs-' + Math.random(),
  EXPERIMENTAL: {
    pubsub: true,
  },
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
      ],
      API: '',
      Gateway: '',
    }
  }
});
```

I don't have a good explanation for why, but [my webapp](https://github.com/npfoss/drsp) doing the same thing (webpacked js-ipfs for pubsub-room) has that config and works.